# Actualizar una variable de sesión con AJAX en Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy desarrollando una función en Woocommerce en donde recibe una variable con `WC()->session->get( 'shipping_calculated_cost' )` pero lo que deseo es que apenas se active ese hook se refresque el precio del envió por medio de la funcion `woocommerce_package_rates` .  Actualmente lo que me ocurre es que toma el valor de la variable de sesion pero se actualiza cuando seleccion el siguiente elemento del `dropdownlist` refresca el primer valor guardado.

Por ejemplo,  si el valor seleccionado en $costo es 10, lo almacena pero no lo muestra. Cuando selecciono otro valor muestra el el valor que se selecciono anteriormente, que en este caso seria 10.

En esta función el valor de `$costo` es un numero dado por un `dropdownlist`,  en este caso le coloco un valor de 10.  También,  tiene activa AJAX para que se actualice.

```
function guardar_variable(){
  $costo = 10;
  WC()->session->set( 'shipping_calculated_cost', $costo );
  foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ):
      WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, false );
  endforeach;

  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($costo);
  die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_guardar_variable','guardar_variable',9);
add_action('wp_ajax_guardar_variable','guardar_variable',9);
```

Esta funcion recibe la valor que se almacenara en la variable de sesión.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'adjust_shipping_rate', 11 );
function adjust_shipping_rate( $rates ){

  foreach ($rates as $rate):
      $cost = $rate->cost;
      $rate->cost = WC()->session->get( 'shipping_calculated_cost' );
  endforeach;

  return $rates;
}
```

En mi Script de JS tengo la siguiente linea para que se refresque la pagina.  Al hacerlo la refresca 2 veces. Y no he podido que se refresque una sola vez.  Esto me trae como problema es la demora en la carga del checkout.

```
$('body').trigger('update_checkout');
```

Comment: No es mas facil solo obtener el valor y trabajarlo con js al final es solo el frontend e igual esta configurado en el backend con la session por si el usuaio recarga la web o cambia de ruta.

Comment: @Bryro ¿En este caso como obtendrías el valor para trabajarlo en JS?